# Long to Wide Format (multi-column counting strings)

Tags: awk, data-conversion

I am having trouble converting from a long format to a wide format:

My data:

```
79264   Bacteria    Firmicutes
79264   Bacteria    Firmicutes
79264   Bacteria    Firmicutes
2947    Bacteria    Nitrospirae
2947    Bacteria    Nitrospirae
2947    Bacteria    Nitrospirae
2947    Bacteria    Nitrospirae
2947    Bacteria    Nitrospirae
2947    Bacteria    Nitrospirae
2947    Bacteria    Proteobacteria
```

What I want:

```
79264   3_Bacteria  3_Firmicutes
2947    7_Bacteria  6_Nitrospirae,1_Proteobacteria
```

My best attempt at this is using something like this below, which would work if I just wanted to average across numeric values in columns 2 and 3:

```
awk '{sum[$1]+=$2; sum2[$1]+=$3; count[$1]++} END{for (x in sum) print x, sum[x]/count[x], sum2[x]/count[x]}'
```

But counting strings and delimiting different strings within the column has proven too difficult for me. I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Is the second column `Bacteria` fixed? If there is a possibility other string than `Bacteria` may appear, please include it as an example.

Comment: Could you please explain based on what condition you want to summarize the lines together? Is it just the equality of the value in the first column? Can the values be interleaved? For example: 5, 8, 5 (again).

Answer (score 0):

**gawk**

```
{
    txid[$1]++; 
    for(col=2; col<=NF; col++)
        a[$1][$col]++
}
END{

    for(t in txid){
        row = t " ";
        for(x in a[t]){
            row = row a[t][x] "_" x ", "
        }
        print substr(row,1,length(row)-2)
    }
}
```

Note:
Searching on '79264' at NXBI Taxonomy browser
leads to
the page for "Paenibacillus ehimensis NBRC 15659"
which is a bacteria in the phylum Firmicutes
which plays well with the integer 79264
representing a taxonomic identifier although the taxon
for that organism is currently NCBI:txid1220562 not
NCBI:txid79264.

Furthermore the other sample "2947" provided does not
return a hit as a taxon.

Could you please tell us what the first column represents?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 2nd field string `Bacteria` is fixed, would you please try:

```
awk '{
    a[$1]++                                             # count "2947", e.g.
    b[$1,$3]++                                          # count "2947,Nitrospirae", e.g.
}
END {
    for (i in b) {
        split(i, c, SUBSEP)                             # split into "2947" and "Nitrospirae", e.g.
        s[c[1]] = s[c[1]] comma[c[1]] b[i] "_" c[2]     # generate a string after "Bacteria"
        comma[c[1]] = ","                               # appear after 2nd use
    }
    for (i in a) {
        printf("%d %d_%s %s\n", i, a[i], "Bacteria", s[i])
    }
}' data.txt
```

Output:

```
79264 3_Bacteria 3_Firmicutes
2947 7_Bacteria 1_Proteobacteria,6_Nitrospirae
```